# How to check data againts xss in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, xss, sanitize

I use nodejs as my backend and store my data in MongoDB. I'm interested how should I check incomming data before saving into database.

I need to check as pure strings like:

```
"some xss test"
```

and object of strings:

```
{
   "name": "xss name",
   "age": 25
}
```

What library should I use for my task?

Comment: Also there is another answer over here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31898933/3765109

Answer (score 2):

It is a general practice to verify the data when you are outputting it, not storing. Doing so, you do not need to worry, what if the XSS data got into database using other routes?

But your question still stands, how would a programmer check if something contains XSS or not. There is a [validator module](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js) exactly for doing this job:

```
var validator = require('validator');

var escaped_string = validator.escape(someString);
```

To verify the object of strings, you might have to iterate manually through the list.

---

If you are actually intersted in outputting html code, but worry for XSS, then you need to use a more sophisticated XSS validator which is kept up-to-date. Example would be [Google Caja](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/)

Comment: So I don't need worry about residing  of xss strings in my Database?

Comment: @Erik indeed sounds counter intuitive. We might want to ask someone more experienced to clarification. It might depend on your situation, but output filtering is safer - if your database is compromised, site will still filter out injected XSS into database. Though noone will hurt you for validating both.

Comment: @alandarev I have never seen a system where validation was solely done when outputting data. Validation usually takes place when receiving the data, before storing it. In the case of XSS your input validation can either deny storing malicious input or sanitize in some way.

Comment: XSS filtering was removed from validatorjs (see https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js/commit/2d5d6999541add350fb396ef02dc42ca3215049e).