# MongoDB injection attack prevention

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Looking at preventing injection attacks on my MongoDB which my API uses.

Private Keys are sent to the API and the API checks to see if the private key exists in the DB:

```
App.findOne({ privateKey: privateKey }, function (err, app) {
  //do something here
}
```

Is a simple search like this (I'm using Mongoosejs) vulnerable to injection attacks? I've read that use of $where can be but not sure whether I need to do anything here to prevent malicious activity.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:** After a little more reading I've changed my query to the following:

```
App.findOne({ privateKey: String(privateKey) }, function (err, app) {
  //do something here
}
```

Is this an improvement?

Answer (score 5):

It's vulnerable to some injection attacks if you do not enforce the type of the `privateKey` variable, for example, if someone sent you the private key `{ "$gte" : "abracadabra" }`, the query could return a document that the client is not supposed to access. Enforcing the type of `privateKey` as String should be sufficient to guard against simple injection attacks.

Comment: *"should be sufficient to guard against simple injection attacks"* - What other measures can we take? Any read-up you can point to?

Comment: @a20, if you are still interested, I've added another answer to this question. In this case, you could sanitize the input with mongo-sanitize module.

Answer (score 1):

As the Mongoose driver follows a schema, you just need to set the *privateKey* to be a string field. If someone passes an object like `{ $ne: null }`, Mongoose will convert it to string and no damage will be done.

Note: `{ $ne: null }` means *not equals null* that would retrieve the first result without knowing its key.

Another option is to sanitize the inputs before using them. For this task, you can use [mongo-sanitize](https://github.com/vkarpov15/mongo-sanitize):

> It will strip out any keys that start with '$' in the input, so you
>   can pass it to MongoDB without worrying about malicious users
>   overwriting.

```
var sanitize = require('mongo-sanitize');

var privateKey = sanitize(req.params.privateKey);

App.findOne({ privateKey: privateKey }, function (err, app) {
    //do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are several solution for MongoDB.

***First:*** There is a multipurpose [content-filter](https://github.com/efkan/content-filter). Also provides MongoDB protection by filtering way.

***Second:*** I'd seen [over here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-identifiers) this solution which can be applied for MongoDB too. It's really simple to implement. Only use built-in `escape()` function of JavaScript. 
`escape()` converts the string into `ascii` code. `$ne` is converted into `%24ne`.

```
var privateKey = escape(req.params.privateKey);

App.findOne({ privateKey: privateKey }, function (err, app) {
  //do something here
}
```

Actually a similar question had been asked [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436467/javascript-nosql-injection-prevention-in-mongodb).