# Adding to existing value with findOneAndUpdate MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to be able to do maths in my query without having to first pull down the data from the db, doing the maths then passing the object to the `findOneAndUpdate`

**Model**

```
var Player = new Schema({
     goals: {type: Number, default: 2}
});
```

**Update**

```
var updatedPlayers = {goals:2};

return Player.findOneAndUpdate(user_id, updatedPlayers, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) return res.send(500, {error: err});
    return doc;
})
```

**Desired Outcome of a find on the player**

```
{goals: 4}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use MongoDB `$inc`[update operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)

```
return Player.findOneAndUpdate(user_id, {$inc: {goals: 2}}, function (err, doc) {
  if (err) return res.send(500, {error: err});
  return doc;
})
```

So it's increase number of goals by 2 from previous value

Comment: What if it's not a number to increment, but text to compare if it's the same?

Comment: you can just do an `update` if returning the updated document is not required

`Player.update({ name: myName }, { $inc: { goals: 2 }}, () => { /* callback */ })`

Comment: Is this a safe way to do it? considering injections etc?

Comment: mongoose node.js package handles this for you, the only user input over here is `myName` which will be used as a filter condition, there is no way to inject any arbitrary command inside. Please check this answer out for more injection cases
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436467/javascript-nosql-injection-prevention-in-mongodb