# Should I validate get parameter with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, mongoose, code-injection

In my routing I have get request:

```
router.get('/getOne', auth(), mapController.getOne);
```

I'm passing id parameter in url and doing mongo query with mongoose in mapController like this:

```
exports.getOne = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const mapData = await Map.findById(req.query.id);
        res.json(mapData);
    } catch (e) {
        return next(e);
    }
};
```

previously I was working with PHP where we were escaping parameters to avoid sql injection. Here I'm not doing anything similiar I just pass `req.query.id` straight to `findById` method. Is everything okey with above code when it comes to security?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript NoSQL Injection prevention in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436467/javascript-nosql-injection-prevention-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case Mongoose would detect that you are passing a string and internally would try to convert it to mongodb ObjectId. If that fails it would not run the query. The error you would get is:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed
>   for value "VALUE HERE" at path "_id" for model "Map"

So as you see you either pass an actual mongoDb ObjectId **or** a valid string which can be casted to one. Anything else would produce a `CastError` by Mongoose.

Comment: Yeah exacly. I saw link which they marked as dup but in the answer there, which have 19+ he says that for example when we have login post request then user can send password like `{ $ne: 1 }` but this is object not a string. When I specify my content-type to application/json I don't really know if user can somehow cheat it. AFAIK he can not inject any js